# How to get Material3 primary/accent colors programmatically?

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

Google introduced Material 3 which allows the user to choose a color to apply for the whole system theme, but their documentation isn't clear and didn't mention how to get current colors programmatically to use for the app such as changing a view's background color or text color.

E.g.: `view.setBackgroundColor(Material3.getPrimaryColor());`

Of course `Material3.getPrimaryColor()` doesn't exist and it is just an example of what I need.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First - bear in mind support for dynamic theming was added in Android 12 (**API 31**) and not all manufacturers support it yet, much less a compatibility implementation for lower versions.

Here is the documentation on how to [use dynamic colors](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming#using-dynamic-colors) in general, including theme overlay and activity color overlay.

If you want to create themed views it's easier to use appropriate `DynamicColor` theme or at least wrapped context to inflate them and let them get stylized accordingly.

To just get specific colors you need to use last step - wrap a context with `DynamicColors` theme:

```java
if (DynamicColors.isDynamicColorAvailable()) {
    // if your base context is already using Material3 theme you can omit R.style argument
    Context dynamicColorContext = DynamicColors.wrapContextIfAvailable(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_DynamicColors_DayNight);
    // define attributes to resolve in an array
    int[] attrsToResolve = {
            R.attr.colorPrimary,    // 0
            R.attr.colorOnPrimary,  // 1
            R.attr.colorSecondary,  // 2
            R.attr.colorAccent      // 3
    };
    // now resolve them
    TypedArray ta = dynamicColorContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrsToResolve);
    int primary   = ta.getColor(0, 0);
    int onPrimary = ta.getColor(1, 0);
    int secondary = ta.getColor(2, 0);
    int accent    = ta.getColor(3, 0);
    ta.recycle();   // recycle TypedArray

    // here you can consume dynamic colors
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't seem to be working, I tested it on an Android 12 device (Pixel) but `primary` shows a purple color instead of the system color.

Comment: @IlyasseSalama it looks like issue was with style argument, I've edited the answer and tested in on API32 emulator.

Comment: Awesome, it works very well. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Pawel I got compile error because `R.attr.colorPrimary` and `R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_DynamicColors_DayNight` doesn't exists. What is the full class name?

Comment: @Max those are resource attributes so they should be flattened and available using your modules package name. As for overlay it originates from `com.google.android.material`, you can try that but if you don't see it you probably have to double check your dependencies.